# Don't redirect to www if it has a certain path via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, drupal

The following rule in my .htacess file, for my Drupal websites, redirects all non www URLs to the www version.  (Ex: `https://example.com` -> `https://www.example.com`):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works great but now I want to exclude `https://example.com/samltest/test` from redirecting to www.  I added the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/samltest/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

But now when I got to `https://example.com/samltest/test`, it redirects to `https://example.com/index.php`.  Does anyone have any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Use `THE_REQUEST` instead of `REQUEST_URI` and clear your cache

Comment: That didn't work. When I replaced it in both spots, it wouldn't access the site anymore.

Comment: Is-it a share hosting? Have you access to your server conf? Via virtualhost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have it like this at the top of your .htaccess:

```sh
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+samltest [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]
```

Test it after clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Thanks. This worked for `https://example.com/samltest/test` but do you know how to have it work for also `https://example.com/samltest`?

Comment: I updated my rule to `RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+samltest [NC]` and it seems to be working for me since I don't have trailing slashes. Thanks for your help.